# How do I delete a voice recording when I have communicated / sent a voice packet in file stream?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, delete-file, steganography

I can't get rid of the sound before, even though I have given the clear button, when sending a sound, the previous sound is still there. is there something wrong ? I need help

```
string TEMP_FILE=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\temp";
string BUFF_FILE=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\data";  



private void btnPlayVoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playMedia(BUFF_FILE);
        lblRecive.Text = "";
    }
private void playMedia(string path )
{if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
 return;
 mPlayer = new SoundPlayer(BUFF_FILE);
 mPlayer.Play();
 btnStopStop.Enabled = true;}

private void btnClearDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (File.Exists(TEMP_FILE))
        File.Delete(TEMP_FILE); 

        if (File.Exists(BUFF_FILE))
            File.Delete(BUFF_FILE);
        lblRecive.Text = "";
        txtKeyDec.Text = "";
        txtMsgDec.Text = "";
        btnPlay.Visible = false;
        btnDec.Visible = false;
    }
```

when sending voice messages several times, the first sound cannot be deleted, so it is still heard when sending the next message. if the code is unclear, then I can give the project, maybe I will get a solution

Comment: A lot of it is unclear, for instance in your SoundPlayer constructor you are passing BUFF_FILE which appears to be a folder path. Also, if your function playMedia is called every time a user clicks on a button, as it appears, the SoundPlayer is instantiated every time, so no way it could be playing the previous sound. Though its not clear it appears to be something related to the audio file path passed to it, may be you are passing the path to the old file.

Comment: @ArifEqbal t seems like you found my problem, what do I need to change?
Do you want to see the whole project ??

Comment: I don't think I really found the problem, but it was my best guess. The whole project might be too much may be you should create a sample which is working and post here, then someone can help.